# Calendário em PHP

Tags: php

Alguém sabe como eu coloco um *loop* nesse calendário, só preciso que ele imprima as datas cadastradas no meu banco.

Da um erro na *query*:

> **Warning**:  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be
>   resource, boolean given in
>   **C:\xampp\htdocs\Shamcey\functions.php** on line **198**

```
function MostreSemanas() {
    $semanas = "DSTQQSS";

    for( $i = 0; $i < 7; $i++ )
        echo "<td>".$semanas{$i}."</td>";

}

function GetNumeroDias( $mes ) {
    $numero_dias = array( 
        '01' => 31, '02' => 28, '03' => 31, '04' =>30, '05' => 31, '06' => 30,
        '07' => 31, '08' =>31, '09' => 30, '10' => 31, '11' => 30, '12' => 31
    );

    if (((date('Y') % 4) == 0 and (date('Y') % 100)!=0) or (date('Y') % 400)==0) {
        $numero_dias['02'] = 29;    // altera o numero de dias de fevereiro se o ano for bissexto
    }

    return $numero_dias[$mes];
}

function GetNomeMes( $mes ) {
    $meses = array( 
        '01' => "Janeiro", '02' => "Fevereiro", '03' => "Março",
        '04' => "Abril",   '05' => "Maio",      '06' => "Junho",
        '07' => "Julho",   '08' => "Agosto",    '09' => "Setembro",
        '10' => "Outubro", '11' => "Novembro",  '12' => "Dezembro"
    );

    if( $mes >= 01 && $mes <= 12)
        return $meses[$mes];

        return "Mês deconhecido";
}


function MostreCalendario( $mes  ) {

    $numero_dias = GetNumeroDias( $mes );   // retorna o número de dias que tem o mês desejado
    $nome_mes = GetNomeMes( $mes );
    $diacorrente = 0;   

    $diasemana = jddayofweek( cal_to_jd(CAL_GREGORIAN, $mes,"01",date('Y')) , 0 );  // função que descobre o dia da semana

    echo "\n<h4 class='widgettitle title-inverse'>".$nome_mes."</h4>";
    echo "\n<table>";
        echo "<tr>";
        MostreSemanas();    
        echo "</tr>";


    for( $linha = 0; $linha < 6; $linha++ ) {
        echo "<tr>";

        for( $coluna = 0; $coluna < 7; $coluna++ ) {
            echo "<td";

            if( ($diacorrente == ( date('d') - 1) && date('m') == $mes) ) {
                echo " id='dia_atual' ";
            }

            else {
                if(($diacorrente + 1) <= $numero_dias ) {

                    if( $coluna < $diasemana && $linha == 0) {
                        echo " id='dia_branco' ";
                    }
                    else {
                        echo " id='dia_comum'";
                    }
                }
                else {
                    echo " ";
                }
            }

            echo ">";

            /* TRECHO IMPORTANTE: A PARTIR DESTE TRECHO É MOSTRADO UM DIA DO CALENDÁRIO (MUITA ATENÇÃO NA HORA DA MANUTENÇÃO) */
            if( $diacorrente + 1 <= $numero_dias ) {

                if( $coluna < $diasemana && $linha == 0) {
                    echo " ";
                }
                else {
                    //echo "<input type = 'button' id = 'dia_comum' name = 'dia".($diacorrente+1)."'  value = '".++$diacorrente."' onclick = \"acao(this.value)\">";
                    $query = mysql_query("SELECT data FROM _atendimento_medico WHERE date_format(data, '%m') = '$mes'");
                    while($resposta = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {

                    if($diacorrente == ( date( 'd', strtotime( $resposta['data']) && date( 'm', strtotime( $resposta['data'] == $mes) ) ) )) {
                        echo "<a href ='". getURL(array('calendar')) ."&mes=$mes&dia=".($diacorrente+1)."' class='consulta'>".++$diacorrente . "</a>";
                    }
                    else {
                        echo "<a href ='". getURL(array('calendar')) ."&mes=$mes&dia=".($diacorrente+1)."'>".++$diacorrente . "</a>";}
                }




                }
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
            /* FIM DO TRECHO MUITO IMPORTANTE */

            echo "</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
}

function MostreCalendarioCompleto() {
    echo "<ul id='slidercontent' class='calendar-consulta'>";
        echo "<li>";
        echo "<div class='slide_wrap'>";
        echo "<div class='slide_content'>";
            MostreCalendario(date('m'));
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</li>";

    $cont = 1;
    for( $j = 0; $j < 4; $j++ ) {
        for( $i = 0; $i < 3; $i++ ) {

            echo "<li>";
            echo "<div class='slide_wrap'>";
            echo "<div class='slide_content'>";
                MostreCalendario( ($cont < 10 ) ? "0".$cont : $cont );  

            $cont++;
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</div>";
            echo "</li>";

        }
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: Onde está o SQL da sua consulta e como o pretende imprimir no site?

Comment: Tente explicar melhor o que pretende ali, eu olho para o código e não consigo perceber o que pretende imprimir ali no dia 20 do mês 12.

Comment: Gostaria que ele cria-se uma class='consulta' a parti das datas cadastrada no banco de dados. ex: quando a data 01/01/2015 for cadastrada no BD a data ficasse vermelha no meu sistema, editei meu codigo pra vc entender melhor, Obrigado pela ajuda

Comment: A minha query da erro

Comment: O erro que notei foi que faltou uma virgula aqui: `date_format(data '%m')`. Se não for isso edite e adicione a mensagem de erro na pergunta.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, adicionei o erro a pergunta e corrigi a virgula

Comment: Pelo erro parece que `mysql_query` está retornando `false`. Qual mensagem `mysql_error()` retorna?

Comment: Retorna, NO DATABASE SELECTED

Comment: Estranho pq minha conexão com o BD esta funcionando.

Comment: Use a função mysql_error para ter uma ideia do problema. Mais [nesse link](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mysql-error.php)

Answer (score 2):

O erro obtido está a dar conta que a função [`mysql_fetch_array()`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array) espera um recurso mas recebeu um boleano:

> **Warning:** mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Shamcey\functions.php on line 198

Em suma, isto verifica-se quando a função [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/mysql_query) não foi bem sucedida, tendo devolvido `FALSE`, como podemos ler na documentação:

> Para comandos SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE ou EXPLAIN, mysql_query() retorna um resource em caso de sucesso, ou FALSE em caso de falha.
>
> Para outros tipos de consultas SQL, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() retorna TRUE em caso de sucesso ou FALSE em caso de erro.

## Solução

O que deverias fazer é verificar o sucesso da consulta antes de tentares utilizar dados provenientes da mesma. Desta forma tens acesso ao erro e podes agir em conformidade para o resolver:

```
// Ligação
$dbConn = mysql_connect("localhost", "mysql_user", "mysql_password");

// Selecionar Base de dados
mysql_select_db("minhaBaseDados", $dbConn);

// Consulta
$query = "
SELECT data
FROM _atendimento_medico
WHERE date_format(data, '%m') = '$mes'";

// Consultar a base de dados
$result = mysql_query($query);

// Verificar se obtivemos um erro
if ($result === false) {
    die(mysql_errno($dbConn) . ": " . mysql_error($dbConn) . "\n");
}

// Continuar com o trabalho
while($resposta = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Penso que o teu erro está na consulta:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT data FROM _atendimento_medico 
                      WHERE date_format(data, '%m') = '$mes'");
```

Estás a utilizar uma função a seguir a `where date_format(data, '%m')` no lugar do nome do campo/coluna onde pretendes fazer a consulta.

Answer (score 0):

Estou usando este mesmo algoritmo de calendário com pequenas adaptações, segue o trecho onde listo os Eventos (registros no banco) no calendário, lembrando que este trecho está dentro do loop de geração das colunas:

```
$dataCalendario = formataDia($diacorrente+1)."/".$mes."/".$ano;

                    # PESQUISANDO SE O USUÁRIO TEM ALGUM EVENTO CADASTRADO EM DETERMINADA DATA
                    $pdo2 = Connection::Conexao();
                    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM EVENTOS as evt WHERE evt.USUARIOS_idUSUARIO=".$id." AND evt.DATA='".$dataCalendario."'";
                    $query2 = $pdo2->prepare($sql2);
                    $query2->execute();

                    # SE HOUVER EVENTO NO BANCO NA DATA, MOSTRA DESCRIÇÃO DO EVENTO NA RESPSCTIVA DATA
                    if( $query2->rowCount() > 0) { 

                        echo "<a href=../views/templateEvento.php?user=".$id."&d=".($diacorrente+1)."&m=".$mes."&a=".$ano.">".++$diacorrente.'</a>';

                        # PEGANDO TODOS OS EVENTOS ENCONTRADOS PARA A DATA E LISTA NO CALENDÁRIO
                        while($reg = $query2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 

                            $descArray = array($reg["idEVENTO"] => $reg["TITULO"]);

                            foreach ($descArray as $value) {
                                echo "<br /> <a class=evento >".$value."</a>";
                            }
                        }     

                    } else { 

                        echo "<a href=../views/templateEvento.php?user=".$id."&d=".($diacorrente+1)."&m=".$mes."&a=".$ano.">".++$diacorrente.'</a>';
                    } 

unset($descArray);
unset($pdo2);
unset($query2);
$sql2="";
```